# Good way to print all time intervals from event object

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working with an event object that includes a start and end time. I want to print out all of the intervals for some arraylist of event objects, but can only think of a trival brute-force solution. 
Assume our arraylist has the following events:

Event 1: start = 130, end = 145

Event 2: start = 135, end = 155

Event 3: start = 145, end = 155

Event 4: start = 215, end = 230

Event 5: start = 215, end = 230

Then we would want to print something like:

130 - 135

135 - 145

145 - 155

215 - 230

All I can think of so far is to sort the arraylist based on start time. For every start time, iterate through the entire list and pick the minimum of the smallest start time and end time that is greater than that start time. This solution seems brute force and inefficient when more events are added. Note that I can always choose another data structure if need be - I read up a bit on interval trees but I'm not sure if that's useful in this case.

I am looking for advice on the best data structure for storing the events and a good algorithm to print all valid intervals (hopefully better than the one I've thought of). Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Could you specify your output? why 130-135, the second event started only in 145. why 215-230. there is nothing in 230

Comment: Because an interval in this case means nothing has changed. 130-135 only event 1 has occurred, but between 135 and 145 both events 1 and 2 are occurring.

Comment: do you need smth like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm

Comment: I wrote an answer with a data structure to hold the events which is good for adding new ones and printing the intervals - and also explained the algorithm for adding new events while maintaining the integrity of the structure. If you want a code example let me know, it's not complex to write. I hope you'll have a look. If you think it will work for you, could I suggest accepting the answer by clicking on the gray check mark next to it, making it green?

Comment: Not sure it covers your use-case 100%, but perhaps take a look at Guava's [Range class](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.guava/guava/23.0/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) and see if it could be modified or used to fulfill your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using an linked list of sets. Each node in the linked list only includes the interval beginning and end times within the node, and the attached set has the original event objects with all their data.

The core concept is that any added event is put with its interval in order in the linked list, and if it intersects in any way with an existing interval it splits it accordingly. If you want to support removing events as well, then any event you remove will either remove an interval or cause some of them to converge.

The printout of the intervals is built into the solution: the linked list is the intervals in order of occurrence (no overlap, as you described), with the events attached in a set per interval. You could just iterate over the intervals regardless of the number of associated events and print out the nodes.

a little notation:

- `se` - start time of event
- `ee` - end time of event
- `si` - start time of interval node in the list
- `ei` - end time of interval node in the list

To describe building this data structure, lets describe first how to add a new event into it. the algorithm has many cases for different intersections which makes it a bit of a long read - but easy to code:

1. end case: If the list is empty, create a new list node as root with the event start and end times and create its set, adding the new event as the first member in the set.
2. end case: If you're at the end of the list, create a new interval list node for the new event and connect it to the previous node.
3. If the current list node is completely larger than the event time (the interval happens after the event end time) - create a new interval list node for the new event and place it before the current node, chaining it correctly with the previous interval node.
4. If the current list node is completely smaller than the event time (the interval happens before the event start time) - go one node ahead.
5. If the current list node is completely contained within the new event (the interval node start time `si` is after the event start time `ei` and the interval node end time `se` is before the event end time `ee`) - create two new interval nodes, one before the current interval and one after and chain them corretly- `{se-si}{si-ei}{ei-ee}` - adding the event to all three associated sets. the two new nodes will only have the new event in their set, the original node will have all its events with the new one added to the set.
6. If the current list node completely contains the event (`si` is before `se`, `ee` is before `ei`) - create two new nodes for before and after, chain them correctly, add the interval's set of events to the new nodes, change the middle node's values to be `{se-ee}`, so you have a chain: `{si-se}{se-ee}{ee-ei}`. Add the new event only to the set held by the middle node.
7. if the current list interval node starts with the event, but ends before it (`se=si`, but `ei<ee`), create a new node `{ei-ee}` with just the new event in its set, and add it after the current node (chaining it correctly), and also add the event to the current list node.
8. if the current list interval node ends with the event, but starts after the event start (`se>si`, but `ei=ee`), create a new node `{se-si}` with just the new event in its set, and add it before the current node (chaining it correctly), and also add the event to the current list node.
9. if the current list interval node starts with the event but ends before the interval (`se=si`, but `ei>ee`), create a new node `{ee-ei}` with all of the existing list node events copied into its set plus the new event, and chain it after the current node. Also change the current node from `{si-ei}` to `{si-ee}`.
10. if the current list node starts before the event but they end together (`se<si`, but `ei=ee`), create a new node `{se-si}` with all of the existing list node events copied into its set plus the new event, and chain it before the current node. Also change the current node from `{si-ei}` to `{se-ei}`.
11. If the current list interval node starts after the event begins and also ends after the event ends (`se<si` and `ee<ei`), create two new nodes around the current one, and change the current interval as we did before to be - `{se-si}{si-ee}{ee-ei}`. The first interval in this trio will only have the new event in its set, the middle one will have all the original node's set plus the new event, and the last one will only have the original node's set.
12. If the current list interval node starts before the event begins and also ends before the event ends (`se>si` and `ee>ei`), create two new nodes around the current one, and change the current interval as we did before to be - `{si-se}{se-ei}{ei-ee}`. The last interval in this trio will only have the new event in its set, the middle one will have all the original node's set plus the new event, and the first one will only have the original node's set.
13. and lastly, if the event matches the interval exactly, just add it to the set.

The result is that you have a list of intervals which are not overlapping and are in order of time, you can iterate over them to print without issue and you can say for each interval which events happen at that interval. You can easily modify the implementation of the algorithm to include removing events, or if you need to search it you could change it from linked list to an array list to use binary search.